# How to delete another item(not the one you are holding) while Iterating the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I've tried to search over the internet to find a solution of deleting another item but not the one you are visiting. Unfortunately, there is not a way to do it.

Here is the problem.

Assume I have a hashmap  and
the items are <0,10>  <1,20> <2,30>

```
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() ;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> >entries = map.entrySet().iterator();

    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
        int temp = entry.getValue();
        if (temp==0){
            map.remove(2);  //2 is the key of 3th item
        }
    }
```

Then the problem occours. 
Really appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: I didn't understand on what line the problem is? and what the actual problem is ?

Comment: map.remove(2).
you couldn't do that. when the iterations go to the 3th entry, the entry is missing.

Comment: If you can describe why you think you need to be able to remove items while iterating through the Map, someone may be able to provide an alternative to your approach that works well.

Comment: Hi, I elaborate the problem more detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949910/detailedhashmap-delete-further-item-not-the-one-you-are-visiting-while-itera
If you have time, plz have a look.

Answer (score 5):

Do it in two passes:

1. iterate through the entries, and collect the keys to delete in a `Set<Integer>`
2. iterate over the set, and remove all the keys it contains from the map. (Or call `map.keySet().removeAll(keysToRemove)`)

Comment: +1,  But, in step 2, use removeAll() instead of remove to save iteration.

Comment: There is no removeAll() in Map. The alternative is map.keySet().removeAll(set).

Comment: while it is only part of my program. I need to iterate the rest entries, and these entries must already have been exclude from the previous results.

Comment: Then restart the iteration, or use an object containing a `removed` flag as the value of the map, and mark the object as removed instead of removing it physically from the map.

Comment: i thought that. and now it seems there is no smart way to do it but restart the iteration. darn

Comment: @JB Nizet Good catch.  I had missed that he was dealing with a Map, not a Collection.  I see you added the idea to your answer.

Comment: @camerist.fan: have you read my suggestion to mark the entries as removed instead of physically removing them? You could then have only two iterations: one that marks the objects to remove, and one which actually removes them. It would be more efficient that restarting the iteration at each removal.

Comment: @JBNizet I elaborate the problem more detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949910/detailedhashmap-delete-further-item-not-the-one-you-are-visiting-while-itera
If you have time, plz have a look. I don't think flag is good solution, either.

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess, you're getting a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

That's baked in. The javadocs say it may be thrown if you do what you're doing. You can either follow [@JBNizet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947575/4893) or you can restart iterating each time you remove an element. Which you choose will depend upon your specific situation.

A 3rd option is to create a copy of the entry set and iterate over that. This one works best if restarting the iteration is expensive and you need to remove quickly.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> >entries = new HashSet<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(map.entrySet()).iterator();
```

Comment: Bingo. I guess the only solution fits my needs is to restart the iteration. Darn.....

Answer (score 2):

Do it in 2 passes, 1st accumulate keys to remove, then perform actual removal:

```
List<Integer> keysToRemove = ...

while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    int temp = entry.getValue();
    if (temp==0){
        keysToRemove.add(2);
    }
 }

for (Integer key : keysToRemove)
    map.remove(key);
```

Comment: Hi Victor,
Thanks for you efforts. However, it is not that easy.
While the above code is only part of my program. I need to iterate the rest entries, and these entries must already have been exclude from the previous results otherwise, they would affect the results i want to get

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a HashMap while iterating through it. Instead, you could for example collect a list of keys to remove while iterating through the map, and then remove the items in the list from the map after you have completed the iterating.