# [Detailed]HashMap delete further item (not the one you are visiting) while iterating?

Tags: java, graph

I wanna use the adjacency list to convert the normal graph to a star graph.

My idea is to use HashMap< Interger， ArrayList< Integer >> to store the points and their adjacency lists. Assume, we have

1-{2}; 2-{3,4} 3-{2,4} 5-{6} 6-{5}   => The result I want 1-{2,3,4} 5-{6}

And I iterate the hashmap and related arraylist. If the iterating item of hashmap's arraylist is the key of further hashmap item. I subtract the arraylist items from the further hashmap item based on certain conditions and then delete this further hashmap item to avoid looping them.

However, hashmap iterator is not allowed to delete an further item while looping. Seriously, I do not want to store the removed items in another list and iterate them again to remove these items and it is too expensive if my dataset is rather large.

Thus, thanks for the suggestions on iterating problem or on the data structure.

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;;


public class StarFind {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>() ;
        // contents of the map: <1,[2,4]>  <2,[1,4]>  <3,[1,2,4]>  <5,[6]><6,[5]>

        Map< Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> copyMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(map);      
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while (entries.hasNext()) { //problem here: when iterating 1th, the 2nd is removed from the hashmap and entries.next() is still the deleted 2nd item.
            Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry = entries.next();
            ArrayList<Integer> alTemp = entry.getValue();

            for (int i=0; i<alTemp.size();i++)
            {
                int valueItem= alTemp.get(i);
                if (copyMap.containsKey(valueItem))
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Collection<Integer> tempCollection =  CollectionUtils.subtract(copyMap.get(valueItem), entry.getValue());
                    tempCollection.remove(entry.getKey());
                    entry.getValue().addAll(tempCollection);
                    copyMap.remove(valueItem);
                    map.remove(valueItem);
                }
            }
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting while you go through, you may try setting the value to a sentinal value (null usually), then cleaning up in a second pass.

Answer (score 0):

I like the sentinel value solution myself, but here's another option:

You could define a logical ordering to the keys into your map (e.g. vertex id). Then either by using a SortedMap or a separate sorted data structure with the key values, you can now delete items immediately and still find the next item in O(log(n)). You could use SortedSet, or perhaps just go with a simple List and use Collections.sort().